# c# Trackbar increase/decrease

Tags: c#, trackbar

I am really new to C# and do have a few problems with the trackbar.
I am trying to increase/decreasing the volume by adjusting the trackbar up and down. 
I do have two commands that I can send with a protocol through serial cable, lets that it is "UP" for increased and "DOWN" for decreased volume. after writing "UP", you also write how many times (nn 0-254) you want to increase the volume. e.g. "UP10" will increase the volume by 10.

This is really easy if you have two buttons.

```
void VolumeDownClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {        //writing to serial port
            serialPort.WriteLine("UP10");
        }
        catch
        { 
        }
    }
```

But how would I achieve the same result with a trackbar?
I have tried to play around with trackbar.Value, but without result.

Comment: what is your platform? asp.net? silverlight? wpf? winforms? (etc.)

Comment: I use .Net for my development

Comment: @Muad'Dib - What does it matter what platform he is using.  His question is an underline C# question.  Based on the fact he is using a serial connection it cannot be ASP.net and its unlikely to be a stand-alone Silverlight application based on his skill level.

Comment: @user971266 - .NET isn't a platform. You cannot code ".NET" you either are dealing with Win32 Forms, WPF, Silverlight, or ASP.NET

Comment: because the answer might be different on silverlight or wpf or asp.net or winforms or...  which means you will get a better answer

Answer (score 0):

As a quick guess, but without platform info
If you can get the devices current volume info, then that would be useful to then marry the value in the track bar and the actual volume., and store it in a local value (lastvolume perhaps)

In the valueChanged event, retrieve the new value. Then compare it to the last volume, if its > then send an UP(currentvalue-lastvalue) else if its less DOWN(lastvalue-currentvalue) and store the new value in last value.

You should end up with a working volume control.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the old volume stored in a variable named `oldVolume`. You can use the Trackbar's `ValueChanged` event to determine the `newVolume` and calculate the `difference`. You can then simply write that to your serial port.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to keep track of what the current value is.  This will be used to increase or decrease the volume.

All you have to determine the value increased or decreased, you can do this by checking what the previous value was, and then sending your UPValue or DOWNValue based on that result.

Comment: How would I store this then? If I do int x = trackbar.value;   does not x get updates with the new value all the time?